# Remove all the lines in a txt file that start with a string? (Java)

Tags: java

Right, so say I have this file with the format:

***myFile.txt***

*name nickname;*

*jay epic1;*

*jay epic2;*

Now say I have `String name = jay;`. I want to remove ALL the lines that start with the string `name`

So basically, I want to remove all the lines in a txt file that start with a string. Possible? If so, can someone give me the code? (I learn best from looking at the code itself.)

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: yes possible, better start coding :)

Comment: Sure it is, just code it; however, DO NOT write the file inline. Put the modified contents in a NEW FILE and then rename to the original once the new file is written.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible implementation:

```
    String name = "jay ";

    String source = "/path/to/original/file.txt";
    String dest = "/path/to/new/modified/file.txt";

    File fin = new File( source );
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( fin );
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( fis ) );

    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter( dest, true );
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( fstream );

    String aLine = null;
    while( ( aLine = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
        // Check each line for the string, and write if it doesn't have it:
        if( !aLine.startsWith(name) ) {
            out.write( aLine );
            out.newLine();
        }
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
```